# Having problem highlighting lines in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have some walking tracks displayed on a map using Leaflet. Some of these tracks go across each other as they are extensions of the same walking rout for certain parts of their paths. So this makes it hard for the user to determine where a track starts and ends when I have two tracks that might share a 5km section and so you just end up with a black line displaying on the map and clicking in the area where they are exactly the same coordinates they are just seeing the popup details of whatever polyline got drawn on top.Ideally I think the best user interface would be to just show pin icons on the map for each walk and then when you click the pin it then displays the track and only that one track.Then if I click any other track's pin it then hides the track from before and now displays the new track.

Is there a method that I can do this in Leaflet?

Alternatively if this is not possible I would like to highlight the selected map by making it a thicker weight line. I have tried this, but the problem I am having with this is that for some longer walks it is not highlighting the whole track, just the portion of the geojson that got clicked. My geojson for longer walks is made up of a feature collection of linestrings. So in some of my walks the geojson has an array of linestring items in a FeatureCollection item. If there is a way to highlight the whole feature collection instead of just one linestring within the collection then that would be a good solution too.

Any help greatly appreciated as I am a newbie to mapping & leaflet.
Cheers
Craig

This is what I am using to highlight the line:

```
function onEachParkFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight
  });
}

function highlightFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;

  layer.setStyle({
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.0
  });

  if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
    layer.bringToFront();
  }
}
```

My code that adds each walk onto the map:

```
sb.Append(
  "L.geoJSON(" +
    item["LocationGeoJSON"].ToString() +
    ", {style: lineStyle, pane: 'walksPane', onEachFeature: onEachParkFeature}" +
    ', markerOptions).addTo(map).bindPopup("' +
    walkInfo +
    '").openPopup();' +
    System.Environment.NewLine
);
```

Comment: And what is `sb.Append` exactly?

Comment: That's just a StringBuilder variable named sb in the C# code that builds the page. It is in a loop that goes through all the walking tracks in our database and adds them to the page.

Comment: On one hand, such a technique in C# is prone to XSS vulnerabilities (unescaped quotes and stuff in walkInfo). I would remove that, and add an example of the JS code as it reaches the browser. OTOH, there are two questions here: one is "how to do the UX for clicking on polylines that partly overlap" and the other is "how to highlight all items in a FeatureCollection at once".